# Why i am not able to see output for 100 times in the javascript console even if i am successfully looping through 100 times and printing console.log?

Tags: javascript, loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEY3v.png)This is my output image:

```js
function bottles_of_beer(){
        var i=99;
        while(i>=0){
        if(i==1){
            console.log(i+" bottles of beer on the wall, "+i+" bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, No more bottles of beer on the wall.");
        }
        else if(i==0){
            console.log("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.\nGo to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.");
        }
        else{
            console.log(i+" bottles of beer on the wall, "+i+" bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, "+i-1+" bottles of beer on the wall.")
        }
        i--;
    }
    }
```

I was expecting the output printed in the console 100 times. But it is just printing the output for i=1 and i=0 and for i : 99 to 2 it is just printing one output. Why is this happening can anybody please explain? and how can i display/print the output 100 times in the console?

This is the output i am getting when i call "bottles_of_beer()":

98 NaN bottles of beer on the wall.

1 bottles of beer on the wall, 1 bottles of beer.
Take one down and pass it around, No more bottles of beer on the wall.

No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.
Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.

Comment: The `NaN` is a clue. Javascript is having trouble determining whether you're using the `+` operator to do integer math or concatenate strings. I would use `(` and `)` to help it out, e.g. `"text" + (i-1) + " text"`

Comment: In your last console log, you have to use Parenthesis ```(i-1)```

Comment: THanks guys . got it.. i really did not spot that part. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last console log:

```
console.log(
    i +
      " bottles of beer on the wall, " +
      i +
      " bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, " +
      i -
      1 +
      " bottles of beer on the wall."
  );
```

Everything before the `-1` is fine as a string, but when you have `some_string - 1` JS tries to convert the string to a number then subtract 1.  That's why youre getting NaN.

To solve it just wrap your `i - 1` in the last console log in some brackets

```
console.log(
    i +
      " bottles of beer on the wall, " +
      i +
      " bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, " +
      (i - 1) +
      " bottles of beer on the wall."
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways from which u can solve this
1.You can place , instead of + before i-1

```
 console.log(
    i +
      " bottles of beer on the wall, " +
      i +
      " bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, ",
    i - 1 + " bottles of beer on the wall."
  );
}
```

2.You can wrap in brackets

```
(i-1)
```